# i need a way to find element by full tag in web automation using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, findelement

I'm using selenium and python to web automation. in my program i get some tags that are overlay and i need to remove them.
so if every time i get a different tag like these:

```
1-<div class="bErdLd aID8W wwYr3">
2-<a href="/process.php?d=1">
3-<img id="dawqe">
4-...
```

so a dirty solution is:
define html attributes in a function and search in string () and then extract its value and give them to another function to find element.

is there a better and cleaner way to find element by full tags like above as input and remove them?

Comment: If you grabbed the div class you can just find the a tag from that and it will remove the top layer.

Comment: thanks for replying . it's not always a div tag. it different tags every time